# When to skip which?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

When can I skip the relative pronoun "which" in a sentence?

Let's take the following:

[...] Where along the long shore, which is full of white sands, the gloom of evening engulfs my heart.

In this sentence, if I remove the words "which is" and simply say "where along the long shore, full of white sands, the gloom of evening engulfs my heart" is it acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Not only is the sentence grammatically acceptable without “which is”, it is arguably better in terms of narrative flow.

Comment: What is the rule to include and exclude "which" in a sentence? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: George said that it was 'arguably better' to omit _which is_, not that it would be wrong to include it. There is no rule, it's just a stylistic choice.